# jQuery getJSON for parsing a selectlist and adding to another selectlist

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm attempting to parse a selectlist using jQuery's getJSON. Although, I'm not sure a) that it's possible and b) that I'm doing it right - which I assume that I'm not since I can't get any of the code inside of the getJSON to execute.

The code should grab the value (or text) from each of the items within the JSON file and then add them to the html variable, ultimately populating the Order select with the value of each item in the JSON.

As a side note, when I navigate to "ChecklistItems/GetOrder/" + id manually, I get the JSON just find - so I assume that it's some sort of issue with parsing the file.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Type").change(function () {
            var id = $("select#Type option:selected").attr("value");
            var html = "";
            $.getJSON("ChecklistItems/GetOrder/" + id, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    if (item.Selected) {
                        html += ("<option value='" + item.Value + "' Selected='selected'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
                    }
                else {
                    html += ("<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
                    }
                });
                $("#Order").html(html);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

JSON file example:

```
[{"Selected":false,"Text":"1","Value":"1"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"2","Value":"2"},{"Selected":false,"Text":"3","Value":"3"},{"Selected":true,"Text":"4","Value":"4"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this:

```
var html = "";
    $.getJSON("/ChecklistItems/GetOrder/" + id, function (data) {
        $.each(data,function(index,item){
            console.log(item);
            if(item.Selected)
            {
            html += ("<option value='"+item.Value+"' Selected='selected'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
            }
            else
            {
                html += ("<option value='"+item.Value+"'>" + item.Text + "</option>");
            }
        });
        $("#Order").html(html);
                });
```

### [Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8zR33/1/)

Comment: Hi, Ehsan. I updated my code above to reflect your suggested changes. I see that it works on JSfiddle, which tells me that there's some problem between getJSON and the JSON file being retrieved because nothing is actually being changed in the Order element. Can you suggest a good way to debug this or do you notice any other problems with my code? Thank you, sir.

Comment: check in console, by logging data variable what is coming?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ehsan. I'm not seeing anything being added to the console so maybe it's a problem with the .getJSON line itself... Although, I am confused since inputting the URL returns a JSON file to me and I can clearly view the data.

Comment: I've come back to report that I'm a dummy. I needed to put a '/' in front of ChecklistItems in the URL.
Also, your answer really helped me out! Thank you so much!